# Why does Stack Overflow not force redirect to HTTPS?

Tags: discussion

I have noticed that if I type stackoverflow.com, it stays on stackoverflow.com. It does not force the browser window to redirect to https://stackoverflow.com.

But there is an SSL certificate to stackoverflow.com.

Should it not redirect to https://stackoverflow.com?

Comment: Because it has not yet been implemented. It is finally coming however, see [HTTPS: It's time](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345012)